# (Baby Rudin) To show the set of all condensation points of a set in Euclidean space is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

This is from Rudin's Principal of Mathematical Analysis, Chapter 2, Problem 27.

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $P$ be the set of all condensation points of $E$. Let $\{ V_n \}$ be a countable base of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $W$ be the union of those $V_n$ for which $E \cap V_n$ is at most countable. Prove $P = W^c$ and $P$ is perfect.

I've done the part $P = W^c$ and therefore showed it is closed. But then I'm stuck at showing that every point of this set is a limit point of it.

Could you give me some vital hint for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve done all the hard work. Suppose that $p\in P$ is not a limit point of $P$; then $p$ has an open nbhd $V$ such that $V\cap P=\{p\}$. Is that possible, given your construction of $P$?

Comment: not sure... I've tried to derive a contradiction from this point for 3 hours but still stuck..

Comment: There is a $V_n$ in your countable base such that $p\in V_n\subseteq V$, so $V_n\cap P=\{p\}$. Since $P=W^c$, $V_n\nsubseteq W$, and therefore this $V_n$ isn’t one of the ones whose union you took to get $W$. Therefore $V_n\cap E$ is uncountable, but every point of $V_n\cap E$ except $p$ itself is contained in $W$. That’s a contradiction, because $W\cap E$ is countable: it’s a countable union of countable sets.